# Spring project with REST and MongoDB - 404 pages and nothing working

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to get a Spring project to work with a simple rest service and a repository which fetches data from a MongoDB database. At this moment two separate things are working:

- I can run this simple REST example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
- I can connect to the MongoDB instance and fetch data

This both in separate projects.

I don't see, however, how I can bring these two together properly. At this moment I've tried the following based on several other tutorials and references (for example https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/). We now have 2 configs but when we deploy and try to go to rest url we just get 404's. it's not clear to me if the mapping is alright, I also don't see how the mapping is done in the first simple REST example.

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{emailaddress}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("emailaddress") String email) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(email);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The Application class (as done in the tutorials):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(MongoConfig.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The MongoConfig class (which we assume is about right but not 100% sure):

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "<dbname>";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createPlainCredential("<username>", "<dbname>", "<pswd>".toCharArray());
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("<dbaddress>", <port>), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
    }
}
```

I really hope someone can shed some light on how to this best, we don't need a Spring (MVC) front-end, just a REST service which will get data from our MongoDB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you change the @ RestController to @ Controller and give a try.

Comment: Here is an example: http://codearsenal.net/2015/10/java-spring-restful-web-service-mongodb.html

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, I still get 404 error while running through eclipse tomcat, but I deployed the war in the tomcat webapps and ran through the server which worked for me.